# Python requests-oauthlib - adding parameters to authorization header for Oauth1 request

Tags: python, flask, oauth, flask-oauthlib, requests-oauthlib

In my Flask App, I'm using the Python `requests-oauthlib` library to make OAuth1 requests (https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth1_workflow.html#).  One of the API calls that I need to make require passing the 'diffie_hellman_challenge' parameter in the authorization header.  From the documentation, I do not see anything about adding custom parameters to the authorization header.  Is there a way or another OAuth1 library that I can use to add a custom parameter?  My code is as follows:

```
 from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1

 headeroauth = OAuth1(oauth_consumer_key, signature_method='RSA-SHA256', rsa_key=private_signing_key, signature_type='auth_header', diffie_hellman_challenge=dhChallenge)

 response = requests.post(url, auth=headeroauth)
```

Unfortunately, the server responds with the following error:

```
 TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'diffie_hellman_challenge'
```

Comment: Looks like you have a different version of the library. Try removing the parameter `diffie_hellman_challenge`

Comment: Removing the parameter 'diffie_hellman_challenge' does fix the error but I need to include that parameter in the authorization header for the particular API request that the app is calling.  Any suggestions for how I can add that parameter into the authorization header?

Comment: No idea. The only reference that I found searching is this https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/specs/rfc7636.html but that looks like is for the server side. Maybe this https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/api.html#authlib.integrations.requests_client.OAuth2Session.create_authorization_url could help?